# how to refer to randomly generated x and y values pushed into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

How can I refer to randomly generated X and Y values when these are being pushed into an array. In my code: ax and ay numbers are randomly generated values which I want to refer to at a later stage and use in a loop. I will be generating many objects and I wish to use each individual ax and ay in the calculations. At the moment the system only uses either first values generated or last.  I am a bit of a noob and appreciate the guidance.

```js
function create() {
  ax = Math.random() * width;
  ay = Math.random() * height;

  asteroids.push(new gameObject("asteroid", 0, 0, 0, 0, "asteroid11.png", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ax, ay, 250, 240, 0, 120, 1, 0, 0))
  guns.push(new gameObject("g", 0, 0, 0, 0, "gun3.png", 0, 0, ax + 125 - 67, ay - 23, 138, 78, 0, 0, 72, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
  bullets.push(new gameObject("b", ax + 125 - 67 + 138 / 2 - 14, ay - 23 + 78 / 2 - 15, 25, 25, "ball.png", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to return `ax`, `ay` from `create`:

```
function create() {
  ax = Math.random() * width;
  ay = Math.random() * height;

  asteroids.push(new gameObject("asteroid", 0, 0, 0, 0, "asteroid11.png", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ax, ay, 250, 240, 0, 120, 1, 0, 0))
  guns.push(new gameObject("g", 0, 0, 0, 0, "gun3.png", 0, 0, ax + 125 - 67, ay - 23, 138, 78, 0, 0, 72, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
  bullets.push(new gameObject("b", ax + 125 - 67 + 138 / 2 - 14, ay - 23 + 78 / 2 - 15, 25, 25, "ball.png", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));

  return [ax, ay];
}
```

---

This is not very clear though. A better way would be to refactor the random width and height generation into stand-alone functions:

```
const randomWidth = () => Math.random() * width;
const randomHeight = () => Math.random() * height;
const create = (ax, ay) => {

  asteroids.push(new gameObject("asteroid", 0, 0, 0, 0, "asteroid11.png", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ax, ay, 250, 240, 0, 120, 1, 0, 0))
  guns.push(new gameObject("g", 0, 0, 0, 0, "gun3.png", 0, 0, ax + 125 - 67, ay - 23, 138, 78, 0, 0, 72, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
  bullets.push(new gameObject("b", ax + 125 - 67 + 138 / 2 - 14, ay - 23 + 78 / 2 - 15, 25, 25, "ball.png", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));

};

// in your loop

for (/* ... */) {
    const ax = randomWidth();
    const ay = randomHeight():

    create(ax, ay);

    // do something with `ax` and `ay`
}
```

Comment: I thought it was something simple. Thank you for your time, I am just a noob, coding for 2 weeks, any help is always appreciated.

Comment: No worries!  Everybody has to start somewhere. Have a look at the second option though. IMO this is better than returning `ax` and  `ay` from `create`.

Comment: I have amended what i had to (returned ax and ay) and I am using in the following code, but the code still doesn't behave correctly.

Comment: if(this.bulletX > spaceships[i].spaceshipX+50 && this.bulletX < spaceships[i].spaceshipX + spaceships[i].spaceshipFrameWidth-50
       && this.bulletY > spaceships[i].spaceshipY+15 && this.bulletY < spaceships[i].spaceshipY + spaceships[i].spaceshipFrameHeight-25)
       {this.bulletX = ax+125-67 +138/2-14,
       this.bulletY = ay-23 + 78/2-15};

Comment: You have to be more specific. Do you get an error? If so, please post it.

Comment: after returning values, as per your first advice, the system still reads the last generated ax and ay. The second option you suggested to add to the loop I am digesting and working on now. In my loop I need ax and ay which are random for each generated object. {this.bulletX = ax+125-67 +138/2-14,
         this.bulletY = ay-23 + 78/2-15}; At the moment only last generated ax and ay are read.

Comment: Well, yeah. If you want to access each generated `ax` and `ay` value you have to store them in an adequate data structure (for example in an `Array`). Accessing the variables `ax`, `ay` will only give you the latest assigned value.

Comment: Hye FK. I have figured out and got X and Y positions (ax and ay in the code) into an array with [0] for ax,[1] for ay etc positions. My question - how, where and what I should position instead of my ax and ay in the code below. Thank you for your continued guidance. if(this.bulletX > spaceships[i].spaceshipX+50 && this.bulletX < spaceships[i].spaceshipX + spaceships[i].spaceshipFrameWidth-50 && this.bulletY > spaceships[i].spaceshipY+15 && this.bulletY < spaceships[i].spaceshipY + spaceships[i].spaceshipFrameHeight-25) {this.bulletX = ax+125-67 +138/2-14, this.bulletY = ay-23 + 78/2-15}

Comment: @AlexH I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Can you update your original question and put the code there with an explanation and what problem you got stuck at?